# handling null in a query jpa jpql

Tags: jpa, repository, jpql

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Elective e JOIN e.catalogElectives ce JOIN ce.catalog c WHERE c.catalogId = :catalogId AND e.instId = :instId")
public List<Elective> findByCatalogIdAndInstId(@Param("instId") Long instId, @Param("catalogId") Long catalogId);
```

I have this code.  I want it to work where if someone puts in a null value for catalogId then it will ignore that where clause, so it would just return all where e.instId = :instId.  How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you describe that and why it doesn't work, then it will help us more. If you haven't tried anything, try looking through the relevant documentation and seeing what they say. If they say nothing, then please include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about extending WHERE clause with another condition? An example:

```sql
SELECT e 
FROM Elective e LEFT JOIN e.catalogElectives ce LEFT JOIN ce.catalog c 
WHERE (c.catalogId = :catalogId AND e.instId = :instId) OR
      (c.catalogId IS NULL      AND e.instId = :instId)
```

Comment: That looks right, but when I send a null for catalogId and a valid instId it sends back an empty.  Should I use left joins?  That seems to make it work.

Comment: Yes, using `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` makes sense since `[INNER] JOIN` excludes any Elective without catalogElectives. I have updated the query accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out!